# Как обеспечить кросбраузерность страничке?

Tags: javascript, html, crossbrowsertesting

Я написал страничку, на javascript, то есть все элементы создаю динамически, проверяя ее в Chrome, Версия 58.0.3029.81 Windows 7, все ок, но когда я ее запускаю в других браузерах или ОС, появляются ошибки, например в Firefox win7 input type=date или type=time отображается как обычный input, что делать что бы такого не было, не знаю с чего начать, что в поисковик вбивать?

UPD

Пока я мало понимаю из того что мне сказали, выложу кусок кода

```
var FromDiv = document.createElement("div");
FromDiv.id = "fromdiv"; 
PeriodDiv.appendChild(FromDiv);
FromDiv.align = "right";
FromDiv.style = "position: absolute;"
                 + "left: 1%;"
                 + "top: 0px;"
                 + "width: 45%;"
                 + "height: 40px;"
                 ;

var FromLabel = document.createElement("label");
FromLabel.id = "fromlabel";
FromDiv.appendChild(FromLabel);
FromLabel.innerHTML = "From:";
FromLabel.style = "position: absolute;"
                 + "top: 10px;"
                 + "left: 0%;"
                 ;
var FromDateInput = document.createElement("input");
FromDateInput.id = "fromdateinput";
FromDiv.appendChild(FromDateInput);
FromDateInput.type = "date";
FromDateInput.value = (new Date()).format("yyyy-mm-dd");
FromDateInput.style = "position: absolute;"
                 + "top: 5px;"
                 + "left: 13%;"
                 + "min-width: 160px;"
                 + "max-width: 160px;"
                 + "font-size: 16px;" 
                 + "text-align: center;"
                 ;
var FromTimeInput = document.createElement("input");
FromTimeInput.id = "fromtimeinput";
FromDiv.appendChild(FromTimeInput);
FromTimeInput.type = "time";
FromTimeInput.value = "00:00";
FromTimeInput.style = "position: absolute;"
                 + "top: 5px;"
                 + "left: 65%;"
                 + "min-width: 100px;"
                 + "max-width: 100px;"
                 + "font-size: 16px;" 
                 + "text-align: center;"
                 ;
```

Вот этот код в хроме работает нормально, а в firefox как обычные поля для ввода текста

Comment: Я бы начал с изучения проблемных мест тут http://caniuse.com/ (скажем что касается type="date" - http://caniuse.com/#search=date)

Comment: добавте код к вопросу

Comment: Самое банальное — просто проверяйте всё в нескольких браузерах :)

Comment: @andreymal как исправить после проверки, вот в чем вопрос.

Comment: @ArtGrek13 снова самое банальное — вбивать что-то вроде «input date firefox» в гугл) Ну и ранее упомянутый caniuse тоже очень помогает. Придётся избегать возможностей, поддерживаемых не всеми браузерами, и отказываться от input date/time

Comment: @MedvedevDev дополнил вопрос кодом, не пойму как использовать флаг dom.forms.datetime

Comment: @ArtGrek13, если браузер не поддерживает, единственный вариант - искать полифил.

Comment: Скажем тут обсуждается та же проблема и есть решение: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22983013/how-to-get-html-5-input-type-date-working-in-firefox-and-or-ie-10

Comment: @MedvedevDev что такое полифил? это моя первая страничка...

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/dom-polyfill

Answer (score 0):

для проверки поддержки элементов браузерами можете смотреть http://caniuse.com/#search=input%20date например. А еще есть JS библиотека https://modernizr.com/, которая сообщает вам, какие функции HTML, CSS и JavaScript могут предложить браузер пользователя.